# Doing calculation on an imported data file

Tags: import, formatting

I have a data file which has been calculated from mathematica code and saved in `test.txt`, I need to import the data and do new calculation on it, here is the simple part of the code:

```
prob = 
 Import["/home/Desktop/test1.txt", 
  "Table"]

 {{"9.780659097977332*^-7"}, {"9.0432074782253*^-7"}, 
{"9.264934689099364*^-7"}, {"9.516465106429963*^-7"}, 
{"8.577198332761887*^-7"}, {"1.1079713181045429*^-6"}}

 alpha = 1.1;
 t = Length[prob];

Do[ 
 Shanon = -prob[[i]].Log[prob[[i]]] + Shanon, {i, 1, t}]
Print[{alpha, Shanon}]
```

and here is the output,

```
 {1.1,-1.1079713181045429*^-6 Log[1.1079713181045429*^-6]-8.577198332761887*^-7 Log[8.577198332761887*^-7]-9.0432074782253*^-7 Log[9.0432074782253*^-7]-9.264934689099364*^-7 Log[9.264934689099364*^-7]-9.516465106429963*^-7 Log[9.516465106429963*^-7]-9.780659097977332*^-7 Log[9.780659097977332*^-7]}
```

I have been tried different ways including `Flatten`, `ScientificForm`,...! I am not sure if there is a problem in the way of importing the data or in the format of data.

Comment: Where to begin? `Flatten` the input, transform those strings into numbers with `ToExpression`, set an initial value for `Shanon=0` before the `Do` loop, use simple `*` instead of the `.` dot product operator for simple multiplication...

Comment: HiMarcob, Thanks for reply, I just ignored to include the initialization part to keep the code small and brief here,as I mentioned I have tried the Flatten, changing . with *, the only thing that I was missing  was using ToExpression,now I got it to work...

Answer (score 1):

You need to flatten the list and convert elements to numeric values:

```
prob = Import["/home/Desktop/test1.txt", "Table"]// ToExpression// Flatten;
```

Then you can find the Shannon Entropy (without a `do` loop and initialization):

```
alpha = 1.1;
t = Length[prob];
shannon = Sum[-prob[[i]]*Log[prob[[i]]], {i, 1, t}];
Print[{alpha, shannon}]
```

> `(* {1.1,0.0000793592} *)`

Comment: Hi Mahdi, thanks for the reply and comments to make the code more efficient, seems I was missing ToExpression...

Comment: Hi Setareh! You're very welcome.